# Tooltip flickers when an off screen Item of a ListBox updated (VirtualizingStackPanel, ICollectionView)

Tags: wpf, rendering, virtualizingstackpanel

I have a collection of contacts. Each contact has a Status indicator. Using the VirtualizingStackPanel ItemPanel, when viewing item 1-10, I am expecting any update on, say, item#100 would not cause the rerendering on item 1-10. It seems like they are as I have tooltip (set to 1 min duration) and various other mouse hover indicators which I can see the flickering as any status of items off the screen are updating. Even when I have only 1 item showing on screen (filtered by name search), the flickering still occurs.

Am I just misunderstanding the VirtualizingStackPanel and the way it renders?
I haven't yet proven if items off the screens are not rendering (looks like they don't).
Is this something I should be concerned for the UI performance?
Is there a way to avoid this?

Thanks in advance for any insight on this.

Comment: Is it MVVM? Solution is different depending on how you bind UI and data

Comment: Are you calling refresh() so the displayed list is rebuilt?

Comment: As an aside. I would suggest an adorner decorator instead of a 1 minute tooltip.